# Failed knockout data-bind on database driven page using Hot Towel API

Tags: jquery, http, knockout.js, hottowel

I'm having an issue setting a knockout data bind to a dynamical generated input field. As a quick run down on canActivate(id) I get the details of all objects required on the page and store it within the vm.OPCLayoutVm.

```
var title = 'User Information';
var vm = {

    canActivate: canActivate,
    attached: attached,
    title: title,
    OPCLayoutVm: null,
    UserInformationVm: ko.observable({}),
    UserId:null
};

return vm;

function canActivate(userId) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    vm.userId = userId.patientId;
    if (userID != null) {
        $.getJSON('CoreData/GetCoreData').done(function(data) {
            vm.OPCLayoutVm = buildViewModel(data);
            return dfd.resolve(true);
        }).fail(function(e) {
            logger.logError('Couldn\'t load core layout', e, 'user-information', true);
            return dfd.resolve(false);
        });
    } else {
        return dfd.resolve(true);
    }

    return dfd;
}

function buildViewModel(data) {
    var data_response = data.result;

    return data_response;
}
```

Then once the page is loaded I populate the dynamic fields and if extra data is required send off a JSON request to get it and then store it as a new object in vm.UserInformationVm

```
function attached() {
   fnCreateInformationPageStructure();
}

function fnCreateInformationPageStructure() {

    //Send json request to get all objects
    // go through all objects and create them
    // however on specific objects where data is already present send off another json request to get it...

     // add binding details to dynamic object
     $(inputDiv).find('input')[0].setAttribute("data-bind", "value: vm.UserInformationVm." + (matching data name to the json returned data below) + ".data");
     //request data and add to vm.UserInformationVm
     if (dataItem.DatabaseTableName != null && dataItem.TableFieldName != null) {
         $.getJSON("CoreData/GetObjectData?id=" + vm.UserId + '&tableName=' + dataItem.DatabaseTableName + '&columnName=' + dataItem.TableFieldName).done(function (result) {
         extendObject(vm.UserInformationVm, [result.result[0].column, new DataBindObject(result.result[0].data,result.result[0].columnName,result.result[0].tableName)]);

         });
     }
}

// Other used function 
function extendObject(obj, props) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i+=2)
    obj[props[i]] = props[i+1];
}

function DataBindObject(dataitem, columnName, tableName) {
    this.data = ko.observable(dataitem);
    this.column = columnName;
    this.table = tableName;
}
```

However running through this with everything in place as I would expect, the input field with the data-bind just does not want to show the data in vm.UserInformationVm.(relevant object).

Any ideas?

-Update-

The current data structure of UserInformationvm looks like...

```
 -UserInformationVm
     -userForename (dynamically generated)
     -userSurname  (dynamically generated)
         -data  (ko.observable)
         -table
         -column
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
<strike>Your PatientInformationVm should be an object of observables, shouldn't it?</strike>

Then, you would replace your extendObject function with

```
function extendObject(obj, props) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i+=2)
        if (ko.isObservable(obj[props[i]]))
            obj[props[i]](props[i+1]);
        else
            obj[props[i]] = props[i+1];
    if (ko.isObservable(obj)) obj.valueHasMutated();
}
```

Comment: Had a little play and apparently not, it treats it like a function which of course does not exist. Could be part of the solution though so I'll keep playing, cheers.

Comment: But did you update your viewmodel to include `PatientInformationVm`?

Comment: Ahhh sorry just spotted a mistake in my question all the patientInformationVm references should be userInformationVm.

It's also an object of objects of DataBindObject in which the data item within is the only required observable at the moment.

Comment: Modified the question and also added the data structure I'm currently seeing.